# Odoo 10 - Get translated name

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have a model which points to a `product.template` instance:

In one of the internal methods of the model I am trying to retrieve the name of that pointed instance by doing:

```py
self.related_product_id.name
```

Where `self.related_product_id` in the model is:

```py
related_product_id = fields.Many2one(
    'product.template',
    string='Master Product'
)
```

This will return the name **in the main language**.

How can I retrieve the translated name given that variable `language` holds the translation we are interested in:

```
language = translation.lang
```

Comment: Where or when do you call `self.related_product_id.name`?

Comment: @CZoellner this is invoked inside a method of a custom model. That custom model has this relational field. It works fine but it does not return any translated item.

Comment: Can you add the full method?